# jQuery toggle not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have a list of Regions and corresponding countries..when i click on a region, the list should expand while collapsing all other regions. Also when i click on the same region again n again, it should toggle.
But in my case every things working fine except that toggle function is not working properly on first click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("tbody[id*='titl']").live('click',function(){     
    var nextId = ('#' + $(this).next("tbody[id*='tbod']").attr('id'));
    $("tbody[id*='tbod']").each(function(){
    var hideId = ('#' + $(this).attr('id'));    
    if(nextId != hideId)
    {
        $(hideId).hide();       
    }
    else
    {           

        $(hideId).toggle();
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Could you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ example?

Comment: The HTML is very complex...it is rendered by server and is very dynamic..

Comment: Then create a minimal example that demonstrates your problem. Otherwise we cannot help you (and don't forget the jsfiddle example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you computed nextID with the context `tbody[id*='titl']` selector but after this when you call `$("tbody[id*='tbod']").each(function()` is searching entire DOM for a matching element.

You should write: `$(this).next("tbody[id*='tbod']").each(function(){` so that you are searching nearby elements to the live tbody element